# Laravel mail not overwriting from config

Tags: php, email, laravel

I'm trying to send a mail that should not have the from address that's in the config, I was sure it should be able to overwrite this by specifically setting it during the sending, but it appears not.

Code:

```
    $mailData = [
        'user_id'  => session('user')->id,
        'kid'      => session('apiUser')->profile_firstname,
        'nickname' => $data['nickname'],
        'email'    => $data['email'],
    ];
    Mail::send('emails.invitation', ['data' => $mailData], function ($m) use ($mailData)
    {
        $m->from("no-reply@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], $mailData['kid']);
        $m->to($mailData['email'], $mailData['nickname'])->subject('Client subject');
    });
```

And in the mail config we have

```
'from' => ['address' => env("MAIL_FROM", "no-reply@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']), 'name' => "Client"],
```

It always sends it with the values from the config, not the from I'm trying to specify.

Any ideas would be nice.

Comment: You seem to do everything right. Is it possible the values used by Mail are just the same as in your config?

Comment: No they are very different. The from in config is just static 'Client' where as in the actual code it's trying to set it to someone's first name.

Comment: Did you try setting it to a test mail and name? Maybe somethings off with the variables.

Comment: I have tried just filling in strings directly into the functions as well as the variables, same result.

Comment: Which driver are you using? And which version of Laravel? I just tried it with Laravel 5.1 and everything's working fine on my side.

Comment: using the "mail" driver nothing special.